# How to replace "-" symbol in Pandas without touching the values for pd.eval() later on?

Tags: python, pandas

The problem is when I replace "-", values that for evaluation will be replaced too.

```
df['land_area'] = df['land_area'].str.replace("-", '0')
```

I want to make sure evaluation can proceed without any issues.

```
df['land_area'] = df['land_area'].apply(pd.eval)
```

Data

```
  land_area
0 969 - 2002
1 -
```

Comment: I'm confused )-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to replace `-` only if it won't interfere with `pd.eval()` later on. So you want to replace only if `-` is present and not any other character?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'land_area': ['969 - 2002', '-']})

df['land_area'] = df['land_area'].apply(lambda x: '0' if x == '-' else x)

df['land_area'] = pd.eval(df['land_area'])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   land_area
0      -1033
1          0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'land_area': ['969 - 2002', '-']})

df.loc[df['land_area'] == "-", "land_area"] = 0
```

Use `.loc` to find the rows with only `-`, then set them to `0`.